# Vue Firestore same item keep repeating on scroll

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using VueJS 2 and Firestore for this project.

I have an infinite loading method, where I need the next item to load, when the user hits the bottom of the page on scroll.

Everything is in the same method called getStraps()

The idea is to have a ***first*** set of items to load, and when the user hits the ***bottom***, then it should load the ***next*** batch of items.

***Main problem:*** The first two items are loading as usual, and then another one is loading. But then when I scroll another time, the 4th item repeats to be the same as the 3rd as so on. The variable "lastVisible" doesn't seem to update, so it won't load the following items with "startAfter"
Video: http://recordit.co/TwqEb4SeWe

```js
getStraps() {
  var strapper = db.collection("straps");
  var first = strapper.limit(2);

  return first.get().then(documentSnapshots => {
    var lastVisible =
      documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1];
    console.log("first last visible", lastVisible);
    const straps = [];
    documentSnapshots.forEach(doc => {
      const data = {
        id: doc.id,
        title: doc.data().title,
        price: doc.data().price,
        skin: doc.data().skin,
        type: doc.data().type,
        imgs: doc.data().imgs[0].url,
        colors: doc.data().colors,
        desc: doc.data().desc,
        date: doc
          .data()
          .date.toString()
          .slice(0, 15)
      };
      straps.push(data);
    });
    this.straps = straps;

    var next = strapper.startAfter(lastVisible).limit(1);

    window.onscroll = () => {
      let bottomOfWindow =
        document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight ===
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight;

      if (bottomOfWindow) {
        this.fetchingData = true;
        console.log("fetch", this.fetchingData);

        return next.get().then(documentSnapshots => {
          var lastVisible =
            documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1];
          console.log("last last", lastVisible);

          if (documentSnapshots.empty) {
            this.fetchingData = false;
            this.noMoreStraps = true;
          } else {
            documentSnapshots.forEach(doc => {
              const straps = this.straps;
              const data = {
                id: doc.id,
                title: doc.data().title,
                price: doc.data().price,
                skin: doc.data().skin,
                type: doc.data().type,
                imgs: doc.data().imgs[0].url,
                colors: doc.data().colors,
                desc: doc.data().desc,
                date: doc
                  .data()
                  .date.toString()
                  .slice(0, 15)
              };
              console.log("more data", data);
              straps.push(data);
              this.fetchingData = false;
            });
            this.straps = straps;
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
},
```